# GNOME 3 Shell keyboard/mouse shortcuts

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

What keyboard or mouse shortcuts for GNOME 3 exist ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This should help:

[GnomeShell CheatSheet](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet)

Taken from that page, is a list of main key bindings:

> - <kbd>Super</kbd> key: Switch between overview and desktop
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>: Switch between overview and desktop
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>: Pop up command dialog
> - <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>: Open Application Menu
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Pop up application switcher
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:
>   Cycle in reverse direction in the
>   application switcher
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> *key above Tab*: Switch between windows of
>   the same application in Alt+Tab
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: Pop up accessibility switcher
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:
>   Start and end screencast recording
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd>: Switch between workspaces
> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down
>   arrow</kbd>: Move the current window
>   to a different workspace
> - <kbd>F10</kbd>: Toggle maximize
> - <kbd>F11</kbd>: Toggle full screen
> - <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd>: Toggle maximize
> - <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>: Toggle unmaximize
> - <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right arrow</kbd>: Dock left/right
> - <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right arrow</kbd>: Move window to left/right monitor

You can view the rest of the keyboard shortcuts and modify them by looking at the configuration:

- In older Ubuntu versions: **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Keyboard**
- In Ubuntu 21.04: **Settings** -> **Keyboard shortcuts**

Comment: This is another useful link: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts

Answer (score 3):

To view/change keyboard shortcuts, you must be aware that there are two places with registered keyboard shortcuts.  You need to make changes in dconf for certain options, like moving between workspaces:

[Enabling native shortcuts on Gnome - 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122748/enabling-native-shortcuts-on-gnome-3)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.