# Gnome Shell Ubuntu short cut Keys

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GNOME 3 Shell keyboard/mouse shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36956/gnome-3-shell-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and Gnome shell. If anyone know the keyboard short cut for all the basic operations such as shut down, log off, or for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd> for terminal. I needed the list>

If anyone got, kindly share

Answer (score 2):

[image: This is from 11.10]

You should be able to add custom shortcuts similar to what is available in 11.10. You can also click onto the shortcut to edit it if you like... Unless if they changed that feature in 12.04