# Basic & most useful gnome-shell shortcuts

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

May I know what are the main and best useful gnome-shell short-cut keys?

i want them to switch the windows and select workspaces etc.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/12/top-10-gnome-shell-keyboard-shortcuts/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [GNOME 3 Shell keyboard/mouse shortcuts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36956/gnome-3-shell-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> -  Pop Up Application Switcher
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - Similar to above but in reverse order
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - Pop up command dialog, typically helpful for launching apps
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - then type ‘r‘ and hit Enter to reload Gnome Shell Theme
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or System Key (Super Key) : overview of desktop (same when you slide the mouse to top left corner (Hot Corner))
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - Pop up Accessibility switcher
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Start and end screencast recording
8. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> Arrow key : Used to switch between workspaces
9. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> Arrow key : Moves the current window to a different workspace
10. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - Launch a shell command in new Terminal window

Add a custom Keyboard Shortcut

Go to System `Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` to view the existing shortcuts or to add one or edit the existing one as you want.

[image]

[Source](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/12/top-10-gnome-shell-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: Seems Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Enter are gone on Gnome 3.28.3