# gnome-shell : command to launch message tray

Tags: gnome

How can I launch message tray in Gnome-shell. I mean is there any keyboard shortcut I can use ?

I am using GNOME Shell 3.8.4 version with Ubuntu 13.10. Thank you.

Already seen here : [GNOME 3 Shell keyboard/mouse shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36956/gnome-3-shell-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts) but I didn't found that.