# how can I add options to the right-click drop down menu in gnome?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, nautilus-actions

**GNOME Shell 3.26.2 | Ubuntu 17.10 | Bash 4.4.12**

How can I add options to the right-click drop down menu in GNOME GUI? I want to place an item in the mouse right-click menu that will do `echo "$variable" >> ~/notes/notepad.txt` where `$variable` is the currently highlighted text. Is there a way to apply this to the right-click menu globally, like copy/paste? I want to have this option basically anywhere a cut/copy option for text is available.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the dropdown menus are program-specific, so to add a system-wide dropdown menu item you would need to adjust nearly every single program's menu accordingly, and there may very well be programs where the menu is hard-coded and not easily modifiable.

I suggest you define a **global keyboard shortcut** instead, there are several question on this topic here, e.g. [GNOME 3 Shell keyboard/mouse shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/q/36956/507051) for GNOME Shell. To capture the currently selected text I recommend [`xclip`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xclip), the command is:

```
xclip -o >>~/notes/notepad.txt
```

Note that this does *not* append the content of the **clipboard buffer** (which is filled e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) to the file, but the content of the **primary buffer** instead, which always contains the text you mark(ed). More about this important difference can be found on [Unix.SE: What's the difference between Primary Selection and Clipboard Buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139191/246819),
 [wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard) and [in this excellent article](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).
If you want to append the content of the clipboard buffer, use:

```
xclip -se c -o >>~/notes/notepad.txt
```

#### Explanations

- `-se c` – short for `-selection clipboard`, uses the clipboard buffer instead of the (default) primary one
- `-o` – output from the selected buffer instead of writing to it (default)
- `>>~/notes/notepad.txt` – redirect the output to the file `~/notes/notepad.txt` appending to its content

See `man xclip` for more information.